# How to subtract value from previous observation ID?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a weird data frame where the observations are out of order, and the unique identifiers for each observation are not numbered in a linear, straightforward manner. Provided in the data set is a unique identifier `ObservationID` which uniquely identifies the observation, as well as `PreviousObsId`, which identifies the previous observation before it. I would like to subtract the value of the previous observation from the value of any given observation. How can I do this given that the data set is out of order?

So I want this:

```
ObservationID      PreviousObsID       Value 
256A                  866D              200
611A                  8166Q             415
866D                  611A              175
8166Q                  -                450
```

To become this:

```
ObservationID      PreviousObsID       Value      ValueLessPrevious
256A                  866D              200            25
611A                  8166Q             415           -35
866D                  611A              175           -240
8166Q                 -                 450
```

I hope that makes sense--thanks in advance.

Data:

```
structure(list(ObservationID = c("256A", "611A", "866D", "8166Q"
), PreviousObsID = c("866D", "8166Q", "611A", "-"), Value = c(200L, 
415L, 175L, 450L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: You get those values by subtracting the value of an observation from the value of the previous observation (previous observation being identified by the PreviousObsID not the order of the observations). For example, for the first observation (256A), its previous observation was 866D. 200 (value of 256A) - 175 (value of 866D) = 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is `match`

```
df1$ValueLessPrevious <- with(df1, Value - 
          Value[match(PreviousObsID, ObservationID)])
df1$ValueLessPrevious
#[1]   25  -35 -240   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

One way by creating a lookup (in the shape of a named vector).

```r
mydat <- structure(list(ObservationID = c("256A", "611A", "866D", "8166Q"
), PreviousObsID = c("866D", "8166Q", "611A", "-"), Value = c(200L, 
                                                              415L, 175L, 450L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
                                                              ))
lu <- mydat$Value
names(lu) <- mydat$ObservationID

mydat$ValueLessPrevious <- mydat$Value - lu[mydat$PreviousObsID]

mydat
#>   ObservationID PreviousObsID Value ValueLessPrevious
#> 1          256A          866D   200                25
#> 2          611A         8166Q   415               -35
#> 3          866D          611A   175              -240
#> 4         8166Q             -   450                NA
```

Comment: Hmm...when I run this on my full data frame I end up getting `NA` for every observation. I am realizing now that a few observations have a 'PreviousObsId` that isn't present as an 'ObservationID` in the data set. In other words, the previous observation being referenced simply isn't in the data set. Could that be what is screwing up the lookup? I'm not very familiar with lookups so apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: Also, Akrun's solution works so no need to change yours. I just would like to know if what I described is actually what is preventing your code from working for me

Comment: @rogues77 not sure - should give the same result.